# transition from one page to another jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to figure out how to transition from one page to the next using jQuery mobile. I have a JSON callback function, and once that function returns a value (say YES or NO), then I either want to transition to a specific page or display an error message. Could somebody provide some sample code on how to write this transition?

I get that the href should look something like this:

```
<a href="nextPage.html" data-transition="reverse slide">Next page</a>
```

But how do I call this from within a javascript callback function? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you say that changePage is not working properly? Could you provide some code examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking `changePage` from your callback should accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
Your_Callback(){
    if(YES) {
       changePage("nextPage.html");
    } else if(NO){
       changePage("errorPage.html");
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to share the JS code that's not working for you?

Comment: I was using the wrong version of jQuery. All set now using the latest version...thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a method for this purpose:

```
$.mobile.changePage('nextPage.html')
```

Check de [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html) to see the parameter it accepts

Answer (score -1):

Did you consider writing the page in PHP to create a session cookie?

`session_start();

$url = $_SESSION['back'];'

in the jquery you would use:

`window.location ="'.$url.'";`

or

maybe try `location.href = "myPage.html"`

Comment: I'd rather not convert my page to php. I feel like this is a common problem that should have a simple solution...

Comment: I've tried $.mobile.changePage but that is not working properly